# How to play the song in my website whose URL is available(Not the file)

Tags: html, url

I'm trying to develop the website in which the users can upload photos/songs/videos and can play them.
Now i want include this functionality.
The user can just give the URL of the song and then he can listen to that in my website.
How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

1) Store Media Playback (http://www.osmf.org/strobe_mediaplayback.html)

2) JWPlayer

3) HTML5 Audio/Video Player

4) jplayer

From the above list, i found that **Strobe Media Playback** to be efficient.

Comment: What extensions do Strobe media playback support?

Comment: Playback for a wide variety of content types, including files of type FLV, SWF, F4V, MOV, MP4, JPG, and MP3.

And Support progressive download, RTMP streaming,
RTMP dynamic streaming, HTTP streaming, HTTP dynamic streaming, and live streaming.

Answer (score 0):

Try using audio tag of html5. See here http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp